# html select import options

Tags: html, select, input

My code:

```html
<select name="Opt1"> 
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 

<select name="Opt2"> 
  <!--- same options "Opt1" -->
</select>
```

How do I repeat it? without rewriting it, my select will have more than 100 options and I need to repeat select at least 50 times.

Is it possible to create a hidden div and each select I call that div?

Comment: if the page uses javascript, then you could let javascript create those selects

Comment: Native HTML is a markup language and does not have a does not process logic statements so you would have to use JavaScript or you're back-end language to help you out. Which language are you using Python, PHP, NodeJS, etc to serve the web page?

Comment: This: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h3jf8b5r/1/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can if you are allowed to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Here is an example.. You can add multiple ..

```js
 
  var result = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi'];
  var options = "";
  
  for(let i=0; i< result.length; i++){
    options+= "<option value='"+result[i].toLowerCase()+"'>"+result[i]+"</option>";
  }
$("select").html(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Opt1"> 
</select> 


<select name="Opt2"> 
  <!--- same options "Opt1" -->
</select>
```

Comment: That creat another problem, all of my select type recibe same options:

So... I created class="option_in_select"

in script add 
var class_opt = document.getElementsByClassName("option_in_select");

and instead of  $("select").html(options);
i put  $(class_opt).html(options);

Comment: You have to add few more lines (one more loop).. See here.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/vLqyj78s/